# Why is += with int array not working in a struct?

Tags: arrays, swift, struct

I have this piece of code:

```
struct Struct {
  var data = [Int]()
}
let p = Struct(data:[1])

var a = [1, 2]
var b = [3, 4]
a += b
p.data += b // compile error: Cannot invoke '+=' with an argument list of type '([(Int)], [Int])'
```

So why does Swift accept to add an int array to `a` but not to a similar int array in a `struct`?

Comment: `p` must be *variable*: `var p = Struct(data:[1])`. I am sure that has been asked (and answered) before ...

Comment: @MartinR Bloody Swift compiler messages >:-( Misleads you each time into a different maze. Thanks for that!